# Ошибка при установке django admin tools

Tags: django, django-admin

Делал все по мануалу
в settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'admin_tools',
'admin_tools.theming',
'admin_tools.menu',
'admin_tools.dashboard',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.admin'
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
```

]

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'django.core.context_processors.request',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

при запуске сервера ошибка

> ```
> Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7fd1d7ee2a28> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> ```
>
> "/home/gatapov/pro/pro/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.9.1-py2.7.egg/django/utils/autoreload.py",
>   line 226, in wrapper
>       fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/gatapov/pro/pro/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.9.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py",
>   line 109, in inner_run
>       autoreload.raise_last_exception()   File "/home/gatapov/pro/pro/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.9.1-py2.7.egg/django/utils/autoreload.py",
>   line 249, in raise_last_exception
>       six.reraise(*_exception)   File "/home/gatapov/pro/pro/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.9.1-py2.7.egg/django/utils/autoreload.py",
>   line 226, in wrapper
>       fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/gatapov/pro/pro/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.9.1-py2.7.egg/django/**init**.py",
>   line 18, in setup
>       apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)   File "/home/gatapov/pro/pro/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.9.1-py2.7.egg/django/apps/registry.py",
>   line 85, in populate
>       app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)   File "/home/gatapov/pro/pro/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.9.1-py2.7.egg/django/apps/config.py",
>   line 116, in create
>       mod = import_module(mod_path)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/**init**.py", line 37, in import_module
>       **import**(name) ImportError: No module named admindjango.contrib

как решить? В гугле ответ не нашел

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас ошибка синтаксиса в `INSTALLED_APPS`, пропустили запятую

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'admin_tools',
    'admin_tools.theming',
    'admin_tools.menu',
    'admin_tools.dashboard',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.admin'     #< Вот здесь
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles','
    ]
```

Comment: вот блин!спасибо!